# Firebase Phone Authentication Issue - Component.auth is not registered yet issue in production

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I've implemented phone authentication with Firebase, and I'm encountering an error stating "Component auth has not been registered yet." in the live/production environment. Interestingly, everything functions flawlessly in the test/development setting. Despite using identical keys and setup for both environments, the issue persists exclusively in the live/production environment. I would appreciate any assistance or suggestions. Below are the details of the packages I'm using :

```
"dependencies": {
  "@abacritt/angularx-social-login": "^1.2.5",
  "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
  "firebase": "^10.8.0",
  "flag-icons": "^7.1.0",
  "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.21",
  "moment": "^2.29.4",
 },
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
  "@angular/cli": "~14.2.11",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
}
```

I can confirm that my server is not blocking any port anything as I am using the same server for a different project and it's working perfectly. The only change is that a different project has been created on Firebase for this product. I have added the domain to the authorized domain list too.

Even it is working in our test Dev environment. We tried with removing node modules & package-lock.json.

Tried with downgrading with Angular CLI version as well as Angular Firebase related modules upgrade & downgrade. Nothing is working in Live. We need help as we are stuck in our Live environment & the project is on hold for Phone Auth.